# Como criar Header fixo sem javascript?

Tags: css

Quero criar um header em uma pagina html, estilo responsivo que se adapte a plataforma mobile e a redução da pagina no browser, como faço?

Obs: Nada que li na internet no momento foi de utilizade, quero sem javascript.

Comment: Menu responsivo, que se adapte ao dispositivo em questão

Answer (score 5):

Da pra fazer com css sim!

**O básico:**

HTML:

```
<header>Menu</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
}
```

**Exemplo do Básico apenas com umas customizações:**

```css
/* Header e Nav */

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #342e37;
  color: #fafffd;
  height: 50px;
}
header nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
header nav ul li {
  float: left;
}
header nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
header nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
hr {
  margin-top: 80px;
}
p {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#index">Página inicial</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#sobre">Sobre</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contato">Contato</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<hr>
<h2 id="index">Lorem ipsum</h2>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
  Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
  quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.
</p>
<h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
  Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
  quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.
</p>
<h2 id="sobre">Lorem ipsum</h2>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
  Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
  quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.
</p>
<h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
  Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
  quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.
</p>
<h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
  Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
  quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.
</p>
<h2 id="contato">Lorem ipsum</h2>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
  Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
  quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.
</p>
```

Você pode criar o seu menu no header e utilizar media query para adapta-lo de acordo com a resolução.

Referencia: http://bradfrost.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/

Comment: Mas esse não usa Java Script ? preciso de algo que não use, mas muito bom essa fonte

Comment: @Azevedo  Analise o código da resposta e as referencias, como exposto pela resposta é apenas css!

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar a propriedade width e height em css:

```
header{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Mas se realmente quiseres ter um website que seja responsive à diferentes telas, usa media query (muito fácil):

```
/*-----------RESPONSIVE FOR THE IPHONE SCREEN-------------*/

@media only screen and (max-width:760px){

/*****************************************
         MUDAR PROPRIEDADES DE H1 NA TELA DE IPHONE
*****************************************/
    h1{ 
        font-size: 250%;
        word-spacing: 0px;
        letter-spacing: -2px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        width: 98%;
        margin-left: 1%;

    }
}
```

Comment: Bem visto, corrigo!

Comment: Não entendi o que sua resposta tem a ver com a pergunta. [**seu código**](https://jsfiddle.net/skcf7usw/) não deveria propor uma solução para fixar o `<header>` de forma responsiva? E essa regra de *media query* é para todos os dispositivos, não faz sentido os comentários de "iphone".

Comment: O iPhone foi só um exemplo. Sabendo o número de pixels (width) de cada dispositivo, pode ser usada a mesma regra (com os pixels certos, claro) para o determinado dispositivo.